# Timing issue with autohotscript, fails to dump or open destination file

Tags: script, autohotkey

I've created a autohotscript to quickly dump selected text into my jot file on the Desktop and I think I'm facing a timing error.

The script works like thus:

1. Select text when reading a text file, browsing internet, reading PDF, etc.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
3. Contents of selected text is dumped into my jot file.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> very quickly, it sometimes doesn't come up in my jot file and sometimes when I keep pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> for a long time, many instances of the text appear.

Could somebody please point out what's wrong with this script and how I can improve it.

```
^j::

Clipboard := "" ; clear

Send, ^c ; simulate Ctrl+C (=selection in clipboard)

selection = %Clipboard% ; save the content of the clipboard

FileAppend, `n%selection%`n,C:\Users\jagrati\Desktop\jots.txt

return
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Change `Send` to `SendInput`. This is a faster input method.
2. Add `ClipWait, 2` under the ^c line. This will wait for new clipboard text (but won't wait for it longer than 2 seconds).
3. Add `Sleep 50` between commands. It's not the best solution, but it may help if the first two things don't.

Comment: `2)` seems the most likely solution to me. Sometimes being too fast IS a bad thing.